# cocos2dx "ParticleSystem" incorrect effect when moving?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, particles

I use "CCParticleSystemQuad" to create a particle and add it to a sprite. When I use "CCMove" to move the sprite, the particle effect changes. It does not move.
Who can help me?

Comment: try a different positionType (property of particle system)

Comment: Yes! 
setPositionType(kCCPositionTypeRelative)

Answer (score 1):

try adding particle as a child to the sprite that you want to move.